# Write Local File using Adobe Air Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, air, adobe

This is driving me mad.  I am creating an AIR application and everything is working great.  However I would really like to have a form inside an Iframe that when the user clicks submit saves the file to local application storage directory.  Right now I am able to do this and save the file with no problems when I just access the HTML page not inside an Iframe.  However if I wrap the page in an iframe and hit submit the file does not save.  Any code examples would be very much appreciated.  When I am using the iframe my code looks as follows`<iframe src="jobs/newjob.html" height="800px" width="800px" sandboxRoot="app:/" documentRoot="app:/sandbox"ondominitialize="setupBridge ()">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer finally on a google groups post.  Anyway, for me it was just changing the

```
ondominitialize="setupBridge ()
```

to

`ondominitialize="this.contentWindow.runtime=window.runtime"`